# How to properly declare a global type in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I try to use a global type but when I do, node crashes without any real error.

My `global.d.ts`:

```
import { Method } from 'axios';

declare global { 
    type AxiosConf = { url: string, method: Method, data: object };
}

export {};
```

Then, the following code makes node crash:

```
const postBaseline: AxiosConf = { 
    url: urlObj.urlStr, 
    method: urlObj.urlMethod as Method,
    data: {}
};
```

Resulting in `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What command do you use to start Nodemon? Are there any compilation errors? What happens if you just try compiling (and not running)? Can you run just Node (ie without Nodemon)? I suspect Nodemon may be swallowing the error message – check Nodemon issues to see if anything related has been reported and upgrade/downgrade as necessary. Please don't answer these questions via comments but update your question with new information.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually didn't used global declaration, but rather an export of the type and then importing it

`types.d.ts`:

```
import { Method } from 'axios';

// Axios config object
export type AxiosConf = { url: string, method: Method, data: object };
```

When using it:

```
import { AxiosConf } from "../lib/global/types"
```